# Getting IWin32Window interface of a MMC snap-in

Tags: c#, .net, mmc, mmc3

I'm building my own mmc snap-in using C#, and it one of the actions causes ShowDialog.

The problem is that the show dialog doesn't block the mmc window, So i want to use ShowDialog(IWin32Window) but how can I get the window handle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

I needed to use the `SnapIn.Console.ShowDialog` and not the ShowDialog function of the dialog itself.